# How to delete a hash from an array of hashes based on a condition in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
a = [{'id'=> '1', 'subject'=> 'this is subject 1', 'orig_id'=> 123, 'parent_id'=> 123}, 
     {'id'=> '2', 'subject'=> 'this is subject 2', 'orig_id'=> 456, 'parent_id'=> 123},
     {'id'=> '3', 'subject'=> 'this is subject 3', 'orig_id'=> 789, 'parent_id'=> 980}]
```

I want to filter it based on the condition that if the `parent_id` of one object is equal to the `orig_id` or the `parent_id` of the other object then keep the first hash and remove the other.

From the above scenario, the second hash will be removed and the output would be:

```
a = [{'id'=> '1', 'subject'=> 'this is subject 1', 'orig_id'=> 123, 'parent_id'=> 123}, 
     {'id'=> '3', 'subject'=> 'this is subject 3', 'orig_id'=> 789, 'parent_id'=> 980}]
```

Comment: Suppose `a = [{‘parent_id’=>1, ‘user_id’=>2}, {‘parent_id’=>2, ‘user_id’=>3}, {‘parent_id’=>3, ‘user_id’=>1}]`. What is the desired return value, and why?

Comment: This looks like you're retrieving records from a database. If so, you should be using a query to do this; It'd be much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `parent_id` *and* detect the proper one, otherwise return *all* of grouped hashes.

```rb
a.
  group_by { |h| h["parent_id"] }.
  flat_map do |id, hs|
    hs.find { |h| h["orig_id"] == id } || hs
  end
```

Comment: It is my understanding that if `a = [{'parent_id'=>1, 'user_id'=>3}, {'parent_id'=>2, 'user_id'=>1}]`, `[{'parent_id'=>1, 'user_id'=>3}]` is to be returned, but you return `a`. Are we interpreting the question differently?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I do not know, but this solution was accepted, so...

Comment: The question isn't entirely clear so y'all are guessing what the goal is. Instead, get the question clarified first, then answer.